# RTC interrupt missing periodically

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, interrupt

I am running a STM32F072ZB into standbye mode. The MCU sleeps most of the time (waking up every 1hr to read sensors). As I have the watchdog running, I am using RTC to generate an alarm every 25s (watchdog period is ~28s). So when I am sleeping for 1hr, I am setting the alarm in time now + 25s, then go to standby, woken up by the alarm kick the watchdog and set the alarm to the next 25s etc...

It is working almost fine but for some reason, sometimes the MCU resets because of the watchdog not kicked. That means I have missed the alarm for some reason. I have been doing some tests and over 24 hours it happened 6 times.

As anyone ever experienced this kind of issue?

The code goes here:

```
// Set RTC_Alarm
HAL_RTCEx_DeactivateWakeUpTimer(&hrtc);
util_msDelay(10);

/*To configure the wake up timer to 25s the WakeUpCounter is set to 0xC738:
 Wakeup Time Base = 16 /(32.768 kHz RC) = ~0.49 ms
 Wakeup Time = ~0.49 ms  * WakeUpCounter
 Therefore, with wake-up counter =  0xC738  = 51.000
 Wakeup Time =  0.49 ms *  51,000 = ~ 25 sec. */

HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&hrtc, 0xC738, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV16);
util_msDelay(10);

if (__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB) != RESET) {
    /* Clear Standby flag */
    __HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_SB);
}

/* Clear Wake-up timer flag if it is set    */
/* Flag will set after exiting from Standby */
if (LL_RTC_IsActiveFlag_WUT(RTC) == 1) {
    LL_RTC_ClearFlag_WUT(RTC);
}

/* Clear all related wakeup flags */
__HAL_PWR_CLEAR_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_WU);
util_msDelay(10);
```

Comment: Any periodicity observed with this issue ? BTW what's your brownout reset level in sleep mode ?

Answer (score 5):

The STM32 IWDG runs from the LSI oscillator which is nominally 40KHz, giving a maximum nominal timeout of ~26.2 seconds however the RC oscillator is neither accurate nor stable and can vary from 30KHz to 50KHz giving timing variation from 19.65 to 32.75 seconds.

If the RTC is also driven from the LSI then that is not a problem but if you are driving it from the LSE you cannot guarantee your watchdog will not go off before the RTC alarm, and you should then set the RTC alarm to less than 19 seconds.

That said, if you are running the RTC from the LSI then your calculation for 25 seconds is incorrect at nominally 40KHz, 51000 would be just 20.4 second.  It is ambiguous because the comment suggests you are using the LSE at 32768Hz but it also says it is an RC oscillator where I'd expect a crystal or ceramic oscillator.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding regarding the RC. The calculation was taken from the STM's example, where I did copy paste, and they are using the RC. I am using the LSE. Thank you for your suggestion I will try to set the RTC alarm less than 19 seconds, and hope it will help on the problem.

Comment: @AdiT if the problem persists, then at least we've discounted one possible cause.  Though for a robust application you do need to account for the tolerance.  It is possible to calibrate it, I imagine the thermal drift is much less than the R/C value tolerance.  19 seconds would be an outlier, but drifting from 26 to 25 seconds is plausible.  Test it with a heat-gun/hair drier and freezer spray to see if you can provoke the error on demand perhaps.

Comment: are you familiar if the stm32 has an register that counts the IWDG? I want to capture the watchdog when it goes off, to see the possibly spread.

Comment: @AdiT : Probably best posted as a new question.  The IWDG counter cannot be read.  It runs on an independent clock domain, so reading it would be complicated even if it could be read.  One solution is to zero a regular timer at the same time you reset the watchdog then in a busy loop continuously write that counter value to SRAM then inspect the SRAM value after reset (the linker will need to be set up not to initialise the counter space).  That will give you a reading of the time taken for each watchdog reset.  As a I say post a new question if you want a more thorough consideration.